# Зачем вызывать WSACleanup?

Tags: windows, winapi, winsock, c++, сокет

Разве по окончании процесса не все связанные с ним ресурсы освободятся?

Я имею в виду программу, которая завершив работу с сокетами, сразу же заканчивается.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Прежде всего, согласен с codemo. Выделил память - освободи. Создал объект - уничтожь. Инициализировал сервис - деинициализируй. Не стОит ждать, что сборщик мусора все сделает за тебя...
2. MSDN по поводу WSACleanup:

> An application or DLL is required to
> perform a successful WSAStartup call
> before it can use Windows Sockets
> services. When it has completed the
> use of Windows Sockets, the
> application or DLL must call
> WSACleanup to deregister itself from a
> Windows Sockets implementation and
> allow the implementation to free any
> resources allocated on behalf of the
> application or DLL.

- Вызов WSACleanup позволяет системе освободить задействованные ресурсы... Скорее всего здесь та же политика что и с кучей - память, выделенная на куче просто так не освобождается. Поэтому, дабы избежать утечек памяти, нужно следить, чтобы все взятое у системы было ей обратно возвращено...

Comment: Следует ли понимать, что **на самом деле** по завершению программы (скажем exit() в .exe из консоли) в Windows ресурсы не освобождаются ?

Comment: Пожалуй, что не следует. В действительности, вся память выделенная процессу должна быть освобождена ОС по завершении данного процесса. Однако, до тех пор, пока процесс остается в памяти, память, динамически выделенная процессу не освобождается, таким образом, если Вы создадите новый объект, и поместите указатель на него в переменную, содержавшую указатель на старый объект (не освобожденный), до завершения программы Вы потеряете возможность освободить занятую старым объектом память... - утечка.

Comment: По поводу WSACleanup - при ее вызове уменьшается счетчик "ссылок" (reference counter) для библиотеки работы с сокетами. Библиотека выгружается при достижении счетчиком 0. Если Вы не вызовете WSACleanup, библиотека останется в памяти (до перезагрузки)... Не большая проблема, если учитывать, что практически все современные приложения так или иначе используют сеть... Но - неаккуратность... Сегодня неаккуратность - завтра - беда..

Comment: Собственно, речь о WSACleanup я завел из-за другого вопроса (о многопоточности, сокетах и падающей программы). Там автору вопроса ответили насчет хаотичности вызовов WSACleanup. Мне почему-то кажется, что даже однократный вызов WSACleanup разорвет связь сокетов в программе с winsock32.dll, что может привести к ее падению.

Comment: Вот тут обсуждение: http://forum.sources.ru/index.php?showtopic=223339&st=15
Пишут, что ПОВТОРНЫЕ вызовы могут приводить к деад-локам... Честно - самому стало интересно, что будет. Жаль, нет времени проверять :( Знаю только, что любая попытка вызова функций WSA...(чего-то там) после WSACleanup приведет к ошибке..

Answer (score 3):

культура программирования